# Google Cloud Build - Does support multibranch pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-build

Does Google Cloud Build has support for multi branch pipeline like Jenkins Pipeline? could not see any information on docs related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Build's Build Triggers do support multibranch pipeline and tag based pipelines.

[image]